# Jquery validate checkbox confused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Any idea why this code keeps saying on and doesn't work how expected ?

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
    if ( $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked')) {
        alert("on");
    } else {
        alert("off");
    }
});
```

example here

http://jsfiddle.net/BFf5H/

Comment: Although @Cybernate's solution works, consider to bind the handler to the `change` event instead. This also captures changes that are performed with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use prop added to jQuery 1.6 (I guess)

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert("on");
    } else {
        alert("off");
    }
});
```

2)Use is to check the state

Try this:

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("on");
        } else {
            alert("off");
        }
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BFf5H/2/

3) @Felix's suggestion
Try this:

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
        if ( this.checked) {
            alert("on");
        } else {
            alert("off");
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

As per the URL provided by OP alternate solution:

```
$(".styled").change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
   alert("On");
  } else {
   alert("Off");
  }
})
```

Comment: @Felix: It's better choice specially here since all we care about is the checkbox's state.

Comment: @cybermate - I have custom checkbox's here but it doesn't work no matter what i do :-( http://offline.raileisure.com/ check the over occupancy box

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("on");
    } else {
        alert("off");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(
                function() 
                {
                    $('#myCheckbox').click(
                        function() 
                        {   
                            if( $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' )
                            {
                                alert('yes');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('no');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="myCheckbox" />

    </body>

</html>
```

[Download this solution](http://see.weareinto.com/7qOc)